# Every possible combination

Tags: permutation, combinatorics

How can I obtain every possible combination for a dynamic sized set? can it be done without recursion or methods? I've been trying to figure out how to do it with just loops for the past  hours and can't seem to come up with a solution.

Comment: At university I learned a language called "prolog". It is for problem solving and does backtracking. If the set is big you soon get to the limit of your hardware.

Comment: Without _methods_?  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few methods can be found on the [appropriate wikipedia page](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations).

(note: this answer is overly generic because the OP doesn't go into any deep about what he needs)

Comment: +1 If the OP indeed just wants the iterative algorithm then it is right there under "Systematic generation of all permutations"